# Using requests in Google App Engine local development server

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-requests

I have an SDK for my web service that is distributed as a Python library via PyPI. My library uses [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) for communicating with the backend using typical REST-like requests.

I would like my library to be compatible with applications that are hosted on Google App Engine (GAE). According to [the GAE documentation on HTTP requests](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/issue-requests):

> To use requests, you'll need to install both requests and
>   requests-toolbelt using the vendoring instructions.
>
> Once installed, use the requests_toolbelt.adapters.appengine module to
>   configure requests to use URLFetch:

So I follow the example given there and have this in my library's main module:

```
  if os.getenv('SERVER_SOFTWARE', '').startswith('Google App Engine/'):
        import requests_toolbelt.adapters.appengine
        requests_toolbelt.adapters.appengine.monkeypatch()
```

This seems to do the trick when a client application using my library is actually running on an App Engine instance.

However, when the client application is run locally using the [development web server (dev_appserver.py)](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-local-server), `os.getenv('SERVER_SOFTWARE')` returns `"Development/2.0"` and so the monkeypatch is not executed. I subsequently get these errors when trying to issue requests:

```
ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(13, 'Permission denied'))
```

How can I detect that the host application for my library is running *either* in Google App Engine itself, *or* inside the development web server? Checking for "Development/2.0" doesn't seem like it would be discriminating enough.

Or, is there a better general pattern to follow when shipping a shared Python library that needs support for "typical" network requests?

Answer (score 2):

Digging through the Google Cloud SDK, it seems that Google's own method for determining if we are running in either the production or development (`dev_appserver.py`) Google App Engine environment is indeed to look for either of those values for `SERVER_SOFTWARE`. From [apitools/base/py/util.py](https://github.com/google/apitools/blob/2c0aef2a70456c585958e5fcfc12970e992e9604/apitools/base/py/util.py#L41)

```
def DetectGae():
    """Determine whether or not we're running on GAE.

    This is based on:
      https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/#The_Environment

    Returns:
      True iff we're running on GAE.
    """
    server_software = os.environ.get('SERVER_SOFTWARE', '')
    return (server_software.startswith('Development/') or
            server_software.startswith('Google App Engine/'))
```